# Android: Browser close "window"

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile

I wrote a simple WebUI for Android/iPhone where users have an account with logout function. They usually start the application via a bookmark on their homescreen.

I want to give them a handy button to close the web browser/page once the logged out.

Whit the following script, the browser prevents the action

```
<script>
    window.close();
</script>
```

Is there a workaround that specially works on Android (default browser)?

### Used tools/techniques

- Tomcat and JSP
- jQuery Mobile (1.4.x)
- Android 4.2.x with default browser
- Bookmark on homescreen

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use script to close the browser window itself? If so, you should read about this:

http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-close.phtml

You'll meet some security restrictions with the close() function call.

Comment: I knew there is a security restriction but I hoped that someone knows a workaround because we are in a special context.

Comment: I can not upvote your comment because I only have a reputation of 13 (at the moment).

Comment: Ok :) later if you want then sadin :)